# Adjust pop up container in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, popup, qgis2web

I have a problem wit my current project. When I export my QGIS Project via qgis2web there is a strange behaviour of the map pop ups which are not fitting the content.

[image: Leaflet pop up container not fitting the content]

It sometimes cuts the container size, but I can not find the reason. It happens randomly. Sometimes it is displayed properly sometimes it looks like on the attached picture.

Comment: Without seeing relevant part of the code generated by qgis2web for Leaflet it's impossible to say what exactly is the reason for that.

Comment: Which part of the code is relevant for the pop up container? I'd love to share it with you.

Comment: Since I've never used qgis2web, I can't help you with advice regarding that. It would all be just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

So i figured out what was causing the problem.
.leaflet-popup-content {
width:***auto***;
padding-right:14px;
}

[image]

The width setting to auto in the qgis2web.css sheet produced the error. I just changed the value to 100 px and now it looks perfect.

[image: That's how it looks now]